# write a method called createArithmeticSeq that prompts the user to input 2 numbers, first and diff

Tags: java

```
    import java.util.*;

public class ManyMethods
{
static int row, col, n, rows, columns, listSize;
static Scanner console = new Scanner (System.in);

public static void createArithmeticSeq(int [] list)
{
    int first;
    int diff;
    //prompt user for first and diff to create list
    System.out.println("Choose the first number and diff to create" +
    " an arithmetic sequence.");
    System.out.println("Enter first and diff : ");
    first = console.nextInt();
    diff  = console.nextInt();
    //process to create list of n*n elements
    for (int i=0; i<listSize; i++)
    {
        list[i]=first+i*diff;
    }
}

public static void matricize (int [] list, int [][] matrix)
{
System.out.println("Matricize arithmetic sequence:");
    int i = 0;
//loop through each row
    for (row=0; row<matrix.length; row++)
    {
    //loop through each column
        for (col=0; col<matrix[row].length; col++)
        {
        //populate matrix with values from list
        matrix[row][col] = list[i++];
        }
     }
}
public static void printMatrix(int [][] matrix)
{

    for (row=0; row < matrix.length; row++)
    {
        for (col=0; col < matrix[row].length; col++)
            System.out.printf("%2d" + " ", matrix[row][col]);

        System.out.println("\n");
    }
}

public static void reverseDiagonal(int [] [] matrix)
{
System.out.println("Reverse the diagonals:");
    int temp;
    for (row=0; row<matrix.length / 2; row++)
    {
        temp = matrix[row][row];
        matrix[row][row] =
            matrix[matrix.length - 1 - row] [matrix.length - 1 - row];
        matrix[matrix.length - 1 - row][matrix.length - 1 - row] = temp;
    }
    for (row=0; row<matrix.length / 2; row++)
    {
        temp = matrix[row][matrix.length - 1 - row];
        matrix[row][matrix.length - 1 - row] =
            matrix[matrix.length - 1 - row][row];
        matrix[matrix.length - 1 - row][row] = temp;
    }
}

public static void magicCheck(int [] list, int [] [] matrix)
{
System.out.println("Is the matrix a magic square?");
    int sum=0, sumRow=0, sumCol=0, sumDiag1=0, sumDiag2=0, magicNumber=0;
    for(int i=0; i<listSize; i++)
    {
        sum = sum + list[i];
        magicNumber = (sum/n);

    for(row=0; row<matrix.length; row++)
    {
            //sum each row, then compare to magicNumber
        for(col=0; col<matrix[row].length; col++)
        sumRow = sumRow + matrix[row][col];
        while (sumRow == magicNumber)
        {
            for(col=0; col<matrix.length; col++)
            {
                for(row=0; row<matrix[col].length; row++)
                {
                sumCol = sumCol + matrix[row][col];
                    while (sumCol == magicNumber)
                    {
                    for (int row=0; row<matrix.length; row++)
                        {
                        sumDiag1 += matrix[row][row];
                        }
                        while (sumDiag1 == magicNumber)
                        {
                        for (int row=n-1; row>=0; row--)
                        sumDiag2 += matrix[row][row];
                            while(sumDiag2 == magicNumber)
                            System.out.println("It is a magic square.");
                            System.out.println("The magic number is " + magicNumber + ".");
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    }
            System.out.println("It is not a magic square.");

}
public static void main (String [] args)
{
    int [] list = new int [16];
    createArithmeticSeq (list);
    int [] [] matrix = new int [rows] [columns];
    matricize(list, matrix);
    printMatrix(matrix);
    System.out.print("\n");
    reverseDiagonal(matrix);
    printMatrix(matrix);
    magicCheck(list, matrix);
}

}
```

[image]

i been trying this for sometime and i dont know where i messed up nothing shows up and i dont know how to fix this.These are the questions i had to create this program off.

1.write a method called createArithmeticSeq that prompts the user to input 2 number, first and diff. the method then creates a 1-d array called A of 16 elements ordered in an arithmetic sequence. we were told to use 21 and 5 so the sequence should be:
21 26 31 36 41 46 51 56 61 66 71 76 81 86 91 96

2.write a method called matricize that takes a 1-d array of 16 elements and a 2 d array of 4 rows and 4 columns as parameters. this method puts the elements of the 1-d array into the 2-d array. use the 1-d array A and B is a 2-d array, then after putting the elements of A into B, the array B is:
21 26 31 36
41 46 51 56
61 66 71 76
81 86 91 96

3.Write a method called reverseDiagonal that reverses both diagonals of a 2-d array. use the 2-d array B. after reversing the 2-d array is:
96 26 31 81
41 71 66 56
61 51 46 76
36 86 91 21

4. Write a method called magicCheck that takes a 1-d array of size 16, a 2-d array of 4 rows ad 4 columns, and the sizes of the arrays as parameters. by adding all the elements of the 1-d array and dividing by 4, this method determines the magicNumber. the method then adds each row, each column, and each diagonal of the 2-d array and compares each sum with the magic number. if the sum is equal to the magic number it outputs "it is a magic square" otherwise "it is not a magic square". do not print the sum

5.write method printMatrix to output elements of 2-d array. one row per line.

Answer (score 0):

On this line you declare a bunch of static variables:

```
static int row, col, n, rows, columns, listSize;
```

But you never assign anything to `n`, `rows`, `columns`, or `listSize`, so they have the default value 0, which is causing various problems:

- Although you create the `list` array of length 16, you don't use `list.length` when looping over it; you use your separate variable `listSize`, which is 0.
- When you create the matrix, you use the `rows` and `columns` variables, which are 0, so you get a matrix of size 0×0.
- Since `n` is 0, `sum/n` will throw an `ArithmeticException` (due to division by 0) except that that line isn't run because its inside one of your `listSize` loops.

Meanwhile, the `row` and `col` variables should not exist there. They make your various `for` loops that use them as index variables much less robust because they share the variables and you cannot, for example, nest calls to those methods. You should entirely remove those two static variables, and declare them within the `for` loops instead.

You can possibly remove the rest of the variables on that line too, and declare them within narrower scopes as needed and/or use the array `length` fields instead.